# Error saving keras model: "RuntimeError: Mismatching ReplicaContext.", "ValueError: Error when tracing gradients for SavedModel."

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've made a keras model. It works and trains well. But when I try to save that model, I get an error. For some reason it saves successfully before training, but when I try to save it after training, it does not work.

Platform: Arch Linux. Tensorflow is installed from official arch repos, package "python-tensorflow-cuda", version 2.9.1-1. Works with cuda 11.7.0-2. Python 3.10.5-1.

A piece of my code:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.Input((None, None, 1),),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (8, 8), padding='same', activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=.05)),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(48, (20, 16), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=.05)),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(len(alphabet), (10, 8), padding='same', activation='sigmoid'),
])
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=2e-5), loss='mean_squared_error')

while 1:
    examples, answers = generate_examples(30)
    for i in range(10):
        x, y = zip(*random.choices(list(zip(examples, answers)), k=50))
        x = (1. - numpy.array(x).reshape((len(x),) + x[0].shape + (1,))).astype('float32')
        y = numpy.array(y).reshape((len(y),) + y[0].shape + (1,))[:, ::2, ::2, :].astype('float32')
        model.fit(x, y, batch_size=5, epochs=10)
    model.save('model1') # <- ======== saving the model ========
    del examples, answers
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 772, in _trace_gradient_functions
    def_function.function(custom_gradient).get_concrete_function(
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 1239, in get_concrete_function
    concrete = self._get_concrete_function_garbage_collected(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 1219, in _get_concrete_function_garbage_collected
    self._initialize(args, kwargs, add_initializers_to=initializers)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 785, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2480, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2711, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2627, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 1141, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 677, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 1127, in autograph_handler
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 1116, in autograph_handler
    return autograph.converted_call(
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 439, in converted_call
    result = converted_f(*effective_args, **kwargs)
File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_fileq3rsm21m.py", line 14, in tf__internal_grad_fn
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tape_grad_fn), tuple(ag__.ld(result_grads)), None, fscope)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 377, in converted_call
    return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 459, in _call_unconverted
    return f(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/custom_gradient.py", line 495, in tape_grad_fn
    input_grads = grad_fn(*result_grads)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 3265, in <lambda>
    return ys, lambda *dy_s: self.all_reduce(reduce_op, dy_s)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 3266, in all_reduce
    return nest.pack_sequence_as(value, grad_wrapper(*flattened_value))
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/custom_gradient.py", line 339, in __call__
    return self._d(self._f, a, k)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/custom_gradient.py", line 295, in decorated
    return _graph_mode_decorator(wrapped, args, kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/custom_gradient.py", line 420, in _graph_mode_decorator
    result, grad_fn = f(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 3263, in grad_wrapper
    ys = self.merge_call(batch_all_reduce, args=xs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 3097, in merge_call
    require_replica_context(self)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 336, in require_replica_context
    raise RuntimeError("Mismatching ReplicaContext.")
RuntimeError: in user code:


    RuntimeError: Mismatching ReplicaContext.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/beaver/PROGS/VIN_ocr/train.py", line 37, in <module>
    model.save(fname)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 776, in _trace_gradient_functions
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Error when tracing gradients for SavedModel.

Check the error log to see the error that was raised when converting a gradient function to a concrete function. You may need to update the custom gradient, or disable saving gradients with the option tf.saved_model.SaveOptions(custom_gradients=False).
        Problematic op name: Adam/IdentityN
        Gradient inputs: (<tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropFilter:0' shape=(8, 8, 1, 32) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d/BiasAdd/BiasAddGrad:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d_1/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropFilter:0' shape=(20, 16, 32, 48) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d_1/BiasAdd/BiasAddGrad:0' shape=(48,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d_2/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropFilter:0' shape=(10, 8, 48, 36) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d_2/BiasAdd/BiasAddGrad:0' shape=(36,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropFilter:0' shape=(8, 8, 1, 32) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d/BiasAdd/BiasAddGrad:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d_1/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropFilter:0' shape=(20, 16, 32, 48) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d_1/BiasAdd/BiasAddGrad:0' shape=(48,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d_2/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropFilter:0' shape=(10, 8, 48, 36) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d_2/BiasAdd/BiasAddGrad:0' shape=(36,) dtype=float32>)
```

================================

Update:

Full code to reproduce the issue:

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.Input(shape=(2,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

x = numpy.array([[1., 0.], [0., 1.]])
y = numpy.array([[.9, .9], [.1, .1]])

print('save attempt 1 ...')
model.save('model1')
print('save attempt 1 success!')

model.fit(x, y, epochs=1)

print('save attempt 2 (after training) ...')
model.save('model2')
print('save attempt 2 success!')
```

Full output:

```
2022-06-12 17:13:03.300014: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:975] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-06-12 17:13:03.335967: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:975] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-06-12 17:13:03.336179: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:975] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-06-12 17:13:03.336605: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  SSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-06-12 17:13:03.337973: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:975] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-06-12 17:13:03.338278: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:975] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-06-12 17:13:03.338447: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:975] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-06-12 17:13:03.871228: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:975] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-06-12 17:13:03.871419: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:975] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-06-12 17:13:03.871593: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:975] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-06-12 17:13:03.871720: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1532] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3013 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.2
2022-06-12 17:13:03.872018: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:146] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
save attempt 1 ...
save attempt 1 success!
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 713ms/step - loss: 0.1857
save attempt 2 (after training) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 772, in _trace_gradient_functions
    def_function.function(custom_gradient).get_concrete_function(
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 1239, in get_concrete_function
    concrete = self._get_concrete_function_garbage_collected(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 1219, in _get_concrete_function_garbage_collected
    self._initialize(args, kwargs, add_initializers_to=initializers)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 785, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2480, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2711, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2627, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 1141, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 677, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 1127, in autograph_handler
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 1116, in autograph_handler
    return autograph.converted_call(
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 439, in converted_call
    result = converted_f(*effective_args, **kwargs)
File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_filefxkl9uls.py", line 14, in tf__internal_grad_fn
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tape_grad_fn), tuple(ag__.ld(result_grads)), None, fscope)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 377, in converted_call
    return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 459, in _call_unconverted
    return f(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/custom_gradient.py", line 495, in tape_grad_fn
    input_grads = grad_fn(*result_grads)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 3265, in <lambda>
    return ys, lambda *dy_s: self.all_reduce(reduce_op, dy_s)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 3266, in all_reduce
    return nest.pack_sequence_as(value, grad_wrapper(*flattened_value))
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/custom_gradient.py", line 339, in __call__
    return self._d(self._f, a, k)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/custom_gradient.py", line 295, in decorated
    return _graph_mode_decorator(wrapped, args, kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/custom_gradient.py", line 420, in _graph_mode_decorator
    result, grad_fn = f(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 3263, in grad_wrapper
    ys = self.merge_call(batch_all_reduce, args=xs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 3097, in merge_call
    require_replica_context(self)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 336, in require_replica_context
    raise RuntimeError("Mismatching ReplicaContext.")
RuntimeError: in user code:


    RuntimeError: Mismatching ReplicaContext.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/beaver/PROGS/keras_test/test1.py", line 21, in <module>
    model.save('model2')
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 776, in _trace_gradient_functions
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Error when tracing gradients for SavedModel.

Check the error log to see the error that was raised when converting a gradient function to a concrete function. You may need to update the custom gradient, or disable saving gradients with the option tf.saved_model.SaveOptions(custom_gradients=False).
        Problematic op name: Adam/IdentityN
        Gradient inputs: (<tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/sequential/dense/MatMul/MatMul:0' shape=(2, 32) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/sequential/dense/BiasAdd/BiasAddGrad:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/sequential/dense_1/MatMul/MatMul_1:0' shape=(32, 2) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/sequential/dense_1/BiasAdd/BiasAddGrad:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/sequential/dense/MatMul/MatMul:0' shape=(2, 32) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/sequential/dense/BiasAdd/BiasAddGrad:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/sequential/dense_1/MatMul/MatMul_1:0' shape=(32, 2) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/sequential/dense_1/BiasAdd/BiasAddGrad:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32>)
```

Also tried changing the optimizer. It did not help.

It seems to be a bug in the Tensorflow.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I installed python through `conda` and tensorflow through `pip`. Now it works.

Full instructions:

1. Install `cuda` and `cudnn`: `$ sudo pacman -S cuda cudnn`
2. Install `miniconda3` package from `AUR`. I use `paru` command to install `AUR` packages (you have to install `paru` too for it to work): `$ paru -S miniconda3`
3. Do `$ source /opt/miniconda3/bin/activate` for `conda` command to work
4. Install python 3.7: `$ sudo conda install python=3.7`
5. Check python version: `$ python --version` (it should be 3.7.x)
6. Upgrade `pip`: `$ sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pip` (or without `sudo`)
7. Install `tensorflow-gpu`: `$ sudo python -m pip install tensorflow-gpu` (or without `sudo`)
8. Check how it works with your gpu: `$ python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"` (if it outputs `[]`, it means that something went wrong, and if it outputs something like `[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]`, then it's OK)
9. Clean pip cache (it's not necessary): `$ sudo rm -r /root/.cache/pip/` if you used pip with `sudo`, or `$ rm -r ~/.cache/pip/` if you didn't use `sudo`
10. Always remember to do `$ source /opt/miniconda3/bin/activate` before running python, otherwise the system python will run (for me it's python 3.10)

And now it works!